# how to make calculator valid

Tags: javascript, calculator

i try to find the most suitable solution for my calculator but it doesn't work.
Shortly: when I input any value and click on any button that I extract by data-op in JS,  I wanna show the result in result.innerHTML. But it refuses to work.
here my JS:

```
var first = document.querySelector('.first');
var second = document.querySelector('.second');
var result = document.querySelector('.result');

var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
 for(var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   var op = this.getAttribute('data-op');
   button[i].onclick = calc(op);
 }

function calc(op) {
   var val1 = parseInt(first.value);
   var val2 = parseInt(second.value);
   var res;
  if(op === '+') {
    res = val1 + val2;
  }
    if(op === '-') {
    res = val1 - val2;
  }
    if(op === '*') {
    res = val1 * val2;
  }
    if(op === '/') {
    res = val1 / val2;
  }
  result.innerHTML = res;
}
```

and here is my HTML :

```
<input type='text' class='first'>
<input type='button' value='+' class='plus' data-op='+'>
<input type='button' value='-' class='minus' data-op='-'>
<input type='button' value='*' class='mult' data-op='*'>
<input type='button' value='/' class='divide' data-op='/'>
<input type='text' class='second'>
<input type='button' value='=' class='btn'>
<span class='result'></span>
```

here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/ksena19/pen/ZqXYqQ

Comment: Your example works in Chrome, just checked. What browser are you using?

Comment: Are there any errors printed in the console?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius also Chrome. I used codepen

Comment: The link to your codepen is of a valid working example. I think you wanted to provide a *not working* example?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius No, it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your loop: you are using `this`, but it is not what you want it to be. You should specify it as `buttons[i]` to refer to the element in `buttons` array. Furthermore, you also have `button[i]` one line below instead of `buttons[i]`. Last thing - you will want this as a func `() =>` rather than immediate invocation. Thus your code should look like this:

```
for(var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var op = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-op');
    buttons[i].onclick = () => calc(op);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function

In the `for` loop `this` refers to the `window`. `this` would refer to the element only inside an `onclick` event handler.

Also, you are assigning the `onclick` attribute of the button inside the `for` loop as the return value of `calc` which is undefined. Instead, you should declare `op` as a global variable and add an event listener on the equals button to calculate the result based on the global `op` variable.

On a slightly unrelated note, you should not use multiple `if` statements when comparing the value of one variable; use an `if`, `else if`, and `else` structure or a `switch` statement.

Working Demo:

```js
var first = document.querySelector('.first');
var second = document.querySelector('.second');
var result = document.querySelector('.result');
var op;

var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', calc);

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-op]');
[].slice.call(buttons).forEach(function(btn){
   btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   op = this.getAttribute('data-op');
  })
});

function calc() {
   var val1 = parseInt(first.value);
   var val2 = parseInt(second.value);
   var res;
   if(op==null){
    res = "No operation!"
   } else if(op === '+') {
    res = val1 + val2;
  } else if(op === '-') {
    res = val1 - val2;
  } else if(op === '*') {
    res = val1 * val2;
  } else if(op === '/') {
    res = val1 / val2;
  }
  result.innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='first'>
<input type='button' value='+' class='plus' data-op='+'>
<input type='button' value='-' class='minus' data-op='-'>
<input type='button' value='*' class='mult' data-op='*'>
<input type='button' value='/' class='divide' data-op='/'>
<input type='text' class='second'>
<input type='button' value='=' class='btn'>
<span class='result'></span>
```